# DT don't display first x number of rows

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am looking to hide the first 3 rows in my list when it gets displayed in a shiny application.  To be clear, I do not want to remove these entries from the list, just not display them.  Is this possible within the `renderDataTable` function?  I have provided a simple sample code to display a DT table in a shiny app using the iris data.

```
  library(shiny)
  library(DT)

  df <- iris

  ui <- fluidPage(
    DT::dataTableOutput("projectsTable")
  )


  server<-function(input,output,session)
  {
    output$projectsTable <- DT::renderDataTable({iris})
  }

  shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: `DT::renderDataTable({tail(iris, -3)})`?

Comment: @HubertL That works, what about if I wanted to remove rows 2:4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly:

```
df <- iris

ui <- fluidPage(
  DT::dataTableOutput("projectsTable")
)

server<-function(input,output,session)
{
  output$projectsTable <- DT::renderDataTable({iris[4:150,]})
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Additionally,

```
iris[c(-1,-2,-3),]
```